# Nestjs wss handleConnection(socket) socket.handshake is undefined and cannot access headers to authenticate

Tags: node.js, websocket, nestjs, ws, nestjs-gateways

I have a Nestjs gateway where I'm trying to run authorization logic depending on values from the headers but wherever I'm trying to access the handshake it always returns 'undefined'

I'm also trying this over SSL which might be making a difference.

main.ts:

```
    import { WsAdapter } from "@nestjs/platform-ws";

    app = await NestFactory.create(UserMicroserviceModule, {
      httpsOptions: {
        key: get_ssl("key"),
        cert: get_ssl("cert"),
      },
    });

    app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));
    await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 443);
```

gateway.ts:

```
@UseGuards(SessionGuard)
@WebSocketGateway({ path: "/user" })
export class UserMicroserviceGateway implements OnGatewayConnection {

  handleConnection(socket) {
     socket.handshake // <== undefined
  }
```

session.guard.ts:

```
    const socket_cookie: any = context.switchToWs().getClient().handshake; // <== undefined
```

And also, although I've addeded the session guard on the whole gateway  --- the guard does not trigger for handleConnection()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guards and other decorators don't work for the handleConnection() method in nestjs currently and the handshake isn't a concept that exists on the vanilla socket but more of a socket.io thing, so I just switched to using that and manually ran the actions needed for verifications inside the handleConnection() method.