# How to use guards with NestJs gateway(web sockets)?

Tags: authentication, websocket, nestjs, nestjs-jwt, nestjs-gateways

In my NestJS API, I'm JWT token, stored in a cookie to authenticate my users.

The user will have to call my login controller:

```
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthenticationGuard)
  @Post('login')
  async logIn(@Req() request: RequestWithUser) {
    const { user } = request;
    const cookie = this.authenticationService.getCookieWithJwtToken(user._id);
    request.res?.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie);
    return user;
  }
```

the `LocalAuthenticatedGuard` authenticate the username-password and fill the request with the user, then the cookie is provided to the client and will be verified against any further request with my other guard:

```
@Injectable()
export default class JwtAuthenticationGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}
```

and its associated strategy:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly userService: UsersService,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
        (request: Request) => {
          return request?.cookies?.Authentication;
        },
      ]),
      secretOrKey: configService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: TokenPayload) {
    return this.userService.getById(payload.userId);
  }
}
```

this work perfectly for my post/get methods.

But now I've some needs with web socket, so I tried the following:

```
@WebSocketGateway({
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
})
export class PokerGateway
  implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('AppGateway');

  @SubscribeMessage('msgToServer')
  handleMessage(client: Socket, payload: string): void {
    this.logger.log(`Client ${client.id} sent message: ${payload}`);
    this.server.emit('msgToClient', payload);
  }

  afterInit(server: Server) {
    this.logger.log('Init');
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  @UseGuards(JwtAuthenticationGuard)
  handleConnection(
    client: Socket,
    @Req() req: RequestWithUser,
    ...args: any[]
  ) {
    this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
    this.logger.log(client.handshake.query['poker-id']);
    this.logger.log(req);
  }
}
```

but:

1. even when I'm not connected, the connection is established
2. The user isn't set to my request

What would be:

1. the way to use my auth guard and receive the matching user?
2. For the further messages, should I just keep a dictionary of client.id <--> my users in the gateway? Or is there a way to also receive the user at each message?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a WsGuard specifically to handle websocket context

```
@Injectable()
export class WsGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UserService,
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const token = context
      .switchToWs()
      .getClient()
      .handshake.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]; // token saved as `Bearer ${token}`

    try {
      const decoded = await this.authService.verifyToken(String(token));

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return this.userService.findUserById(decoded._id).then((user) => {
          if (user) {
            context.switchToWs().getData().user = user; // save user info to a user object.
            resolve(Boolean(user));
          } else {
            reject(false);
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      throw new WsException(ex.message);
    }
  }
}




websocket.gateway.ts
See this // https://stackoverflow.com/a/69673979/12624390
@UseGuards(WsGuard)
export class ChatsGateway {

  @SubscribeMessage('findAllChats')
  findAll(client, data: { user: User }) {
    console.log(data.user);
    return this.chatsService.findAll();
  }

}
```